# How to retrieve the value of a key in a dictionary using a variable defined in TAL?

Tags: python, plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

I have defined a dictionary in python:

```
tal:define="dic python:{'a':'1', 'b':'2'};"
```

I have another variable defined using `tal:define` called var, which is either 'a' or 'b'.
I get an error when I try to do:

```
tal:define="foo python:dic['${var}'];"
```

(foo would then be '1' or '2')
I get `KeyError: '${var}'`. I've tried `dic[$var]`, `dic[var]`, etc and they all don't work. How do I use a variable defined previously using `tal:define` as a key to a dictionary to get its value.

Comment: dic[var] should work, are you sure you define correctly 'var' ... can i see the 'var' definition ?

Comment: oh, geez. you're right, I remembered I tried that one and it didn't work so I've been trying some with the '$' and curly bracket combos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DonCallisto's dic[var] does work

Answer (score 5):

Path expression syntax:

```
tal:define="foo dic/?var"
```

Python expression syntax:

```
tal:define="foo python:dic[var]"
```

See [Zope Book](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#id32) for description of ?var syntax.